# Undelete request

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions, undelete-request

Coincidentally, I became re-interested in an unanswered question just as it was automatically deleted (for inactivity, I assume).

It’s here:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/358689/in-tortuga-team-s-spaceland-what-determines-when-turrets-appear

I might even put a bounty on it.

Undelete votes are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't show up as deleted for me..

Comment: @Joachim That is because I am too fast

Answer (score 5):

I've gone ahead and cast the deciding undelete vote, since this was just Community cleaning up a question with no activity for a year.

In the future, a custom moderator flag would also bring this kind of situation to our attention.